# Is it possible to build a python web app without any framework?

Tags: python, web-applications, frameworks

I am currently interesting in web development using python language, but evertime I'm searching for reference, we only given two frameworks option between Django and flask. Can we just develop web app without using any of those framework

Comment: you could check out https://www.reahl.org/ ; It is also a framework, but in pure python.

Comment: If you end up going with flask, I found a great [intro tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) (it's very large but very informative)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can build a web-app using no framework. However it will require you writing a large amount of boiler plate code to send, receive, and parse HTTP data. It is generally highly recommended that you use a framework in order to save yourself a large amount of time and effort, and to ensure the product that you build is good quality.

You will also struggle to find resources on building a web-app without a framework, while there are a wealth of resources available for working with existing frameworks.